# How do I get parameter enforcement to work with for added ScriptMethod members?

Tags: validation, powershell, object, methods, parameters

I have and $object that I want to have built in functions. I cant seem to figure out how to enforce the mandatory rule on a parameter for added functions.

The Mandatory rule works with standard functions not associated with an object, but when I  test the object and run the function I can execute with out the desired mandatory parameter.

```
 $object | Add-Member -Name ProcessFiles -MemberType ScriptMethod -Value { 
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String[]]$FILES
    )
```

This doesn't throw an error and it should complain that there is a missing parameter.

```
$object.ProcessFiles()
```

What's the magic? Does anyone have example code of custom-object ScriptMethod parameter validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is interesting. I can confirm the behavior you're seeing (using PowerShell 5.0, but I imagine it's the same throughout).

I can't say exactly why this is happening, but it must be something about the way the code is invoked.

By doing `$object.ProcessFiles.Script.Ast.ParamBlock.Parameters.Attributes` you can see that the `Mandatory` parameter is preserved, it's just seemingly ignored.

## Workarounds

### A simple test

If you don't need all the functionality of a mandatory parameter (that is, you don't care if it prompts for a value), you could simply test and `throw`:

```
$object | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name test -Value { 
    param(
        [String[]]
        $Files
    )

    if (!$Files) {
        throw [System.ArgumentException]'-Files is required.'
    }
}
```

### Something more generic

While investigating this I noticed that a `[ScriptBlock]` does enforce the attributes, so I came up with this hack:

```
$object | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name ProcessFiles -Value { 
    param(
        [String[]]
        $Files
    )

    & {
        param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            [String[]]
            $Files
        )

        $Files
    } @PSBoundParameters
}
```

This is creating a script block inside your ScriptMethod that accepts the same parameters, and then passing all of the bound parameters as arguments to the scriptblock while it invokes it.

I haven't tested it with more complex parameter declarations, but it should do the trick.

The main downside to this I think is that you need to write the param block twice. There is a way to avoid that if you create your scriptblock outside of the `Add-Member` call; you could create a function that takes a scriptblock as a parameter, then parse it with the AST and programmatically create a new scriptblock that embeds and executes the original one. It's probably bit overkill; maybe I'll write a blog post about it.

Comment: Thank you for you input. It sounds like this is some kind of bug. I think I will use the "simple work around" you suggested to do input checking. Obviously I was simply hoping to rely on built-in magic, but it looks like I have to conjure my own voodoo.